# Drupal 7 intergrating with alfresco

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, alfresco, cmis

Am having problems with integrating drupal and alfresco 4.2 and the cmis drupal modules.

what i have done up to now is .

```
1.Have a drupal 7.22 installed and running have the cmis modules installed and alfresco running in port 8000.
  In the drupal settings.php i have this
```

$conf['cmis_repositories'] = array( 'default' => array( 'user' => 'admin', 'password' => 'nais',

```
 'url' => 'http://localhost:8000/alfresco/service/cmis', ), );
```

---

```
   2. On the browser tis http://127.0.0.1:8000/alfresco/service/cmis this downloads a cmis.xml file 
      that also contains the url within the xml file. this -> http://127.0.0.1:8000/alfresco/service/cmis

   3.  Moving to  http://localhost/cmis/browser gives a 404 error 

   4   My drupal folder is called Tuna 

   5    Following the Readme.txt instruction to access the repository while both alfresco and drupal are
         running and the module  cmis is installed on the drupal by going to 

            http://localhost/cmis/browser  or 
            http://localhost/Tuna/cmis/browser gives a 404  error .


   6  how to i make it work   and view the repository using drupal ?

   7  how does the cmis view module work or does it work when the repository is able to viewed on the drupal part ?


  .Please guide me am yet to be pro on drupal  so a few guides and baby steps explanation would really help
```

Comment: You might want to fix your formatting, as it stands your question is very hard to read...

Comment: @Gagravarr hope its readable now .Do  please me guide in the issue above

Answer (score 1):

localhost/cmis/browser

as you can see the above url it is assuming that you have installed in DOC_ROOT of your apache .. if you have created the drupal folder in docroot ... for example

localhost/drupal_folder

Then it doesn't work

You need to set the browser URL in cmis settings